# Java: Using Enums to implement Interface to get specific properties and keeping defaults in Interface

Tags: java, enums, interface

I have two AWS SQS queues that will use different values for properties like `POLL_TIME_IN_SECONDS`, `PURGE_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECONDS`. I am thinking of creating an interface `SqsProperties` and then implementing it by two enums that will correspond to the properties for the two SQS queues.

This way I would be able to add more properties in enums and use the interface `SqsProperties`. I want to keep a default value for these properties ( `POLL_TIME_IN_SECONDS`, `PURGE_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECONDS`) in the interface. My questions are twofold:

1. I have read many times that keeping constants in an Interface is a bad idea, is that true in this case as well?
2. Is this the right way to maintain properties for the two SQS queues? (i.e. Using an interface for some default properties and then implementing it using enums to get more specific properties)

Comment: I can't specifically address your question.  But are you aware of `EnumSet` where you can use `enum` types in lieu of static flags?  If you check them out you may get the answer to your question.

Comment: `EnumSet` doesn't really address the problem of setting specific properties that override default properties. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Ok.  Wasn't certain. Thought I'd mention it.